# creating rest api for application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have just started writing rest api for one of my app and I want to implement this rest api with can can so that I can provide access control to the app.

Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Following Railscast Episode explains creating Rest Api along with Versioning(which might come handle if u need it)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning

For Access control you can do the same, what other Rest Api's do, create a hash based token and save it in the database.anyone who wants to access the rest api will need to pass that hash token to have access.